# Corelocation and assisted gps iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps, core-location

I have a quick question, does the core location in iOS 4.3.2 automatically use assisted gps or is this an option you need to choose.

I am working with the GPS and I recon that the settle time before finding a good accuracy(below 10 meters) is rather long - a few minuts.

Regards

Bjarke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all automatic. The best you can do is check the altitude, which is undefined when a GPS fix is not available yet.

edit: see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html

if verticalAccuracy < 0, altitude is invalid (from which you can infer no GPS fix)

Comment: Not 100% correct. If having view to 3 satelites the horzicontal position can be valid , but altitude is not. (depending on the GPS chip settings and the ios implentation)  4 or more means having altitude.