# Getting Current Location's Provider Detail in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-location

I have implemented `LocationManager` and getting update of current location in `didUpdateToLocation:` every thing is working fine. Now I want to implement network triangulation, as far as I know that, The location services do this automatically. Just request the 'best accuracy' in your `LocationManager` and it will do network triangulation if GPS is not available or stable.

The problem is that I want to get the Location's Provider (GPS, Network), that which Location provider is providing the location. How can I get the Location's Provider Detail in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer here: [Corelocation and assisted gps iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828992/corelocation-and-assisted-gps-iphone/5829152#5829152)

That should help you tell the difference between GPS and triangulation.

Answer (score -1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

{ 

CLLocationManager   *locationManager;


} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

 @end




The implementation of our view controller is as follows:
#import "RootViewController.h"
 #import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize locationManager;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
{

NSLog(@"Latitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);


 NSLog(@"Longitude = %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

}
```

Comment: how we know that the current location is coming from GPS or Network??