# Possible to Access iPhone GPS receiver data (not just Core Location Lat / Lon)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gps, core-location

I'm fairly certain that this isn't possible but I thought I'd ask. The iPhone gets its location with Assisted GPS by means of giving the receiver the locations of the GPS satellites via the provider's data network but it still does processing to calculate your location. I'm interested in actually looking at the log data from the receiver in the phone. I'd really like to look at the carrier phase / doppler / C/No.. etc (or even the satellite ephemeris as it comes across the network). Is there any possible way to access that sort of thing or is it basically a private thing hidden from the rest of us?

Comment: see also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828992/corelocation-and-assisted-gps-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this is hidden from you, the system determines which location technique it uses depending on the accuracy you ask the location manager and the services available so as to optimize battery use and protect private user data (the user will have to confirm that your app is allowed to access location before you can get it).

Comment: Ok - that's what I expected. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is everything you have access to without Jailbreaking.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123